# Product Stock is not updated via Repository but works ok via Model save() method

Tags: product, configurable-product, stock

## via ProductRepository:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($product['sku']);
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());

$stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
$product->setTypeId('configurable');
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

***StockItem is not updated!!***
**Product is saved. But Stock is not (or rolled back).**
If comment the last line in code above (product saving) - stock will updated ok.

## via Model \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product:

```
$productModel = $this->productFactory->create();
$product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $product['sku']);
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());

$stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
$product->setTypeId('configurable');
$product->save($product);
```

**Both - StockItem and Product updated!**

How to update stock and update product in Magento way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because product loaded from Repository contains deprecated data:

```
  ["quantity_and_stock_status"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["is_in_stock"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["qty"]=>
    float(0)
  }
```

That's why productRepository->save($product) overwrites previously saved stock item.

So correct code is:

```php
$product = $this->productRepository->get($product['sku']);

//Magento way
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
$stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);

$product->setTypeId('configurable');

//Deprecated workaround
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(1);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```